# How to execute this t-sql script that syntax checking does not allow me?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, powershell, sql-server-2012

This script fails to execute from PowerShell (sqlcmd) and directly from SQL Management Studio:

```
IF db_id('BANANATEST') is not null
 BEGIN   
  print 'DB BANANATEST already exists. NO ACTION TAKEN.'
 END
ELSE
 BEGIN
  print 'DB BANANATEST does NOT exist.'
  print 'Restoring a backup of BANANATEST'
  RESTORE DATABASE BANANATEST
   FROM DISK = 'BANANATEST.original.bak' ;

  print 'Creating User BANANATEST'
  USE master
  If Exists (select loginname from master.dbo.syslogins where name ='BANANATEST')
  Begin
   DROP LOGIN [BANANATEST]
  END
  CREATE LOGIN [BANANATEST] WITH PASSWORD=N'BANANATEST', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
  USE BANANATEST
  ALTER USER [BANANATEST] WITH LOGIN = [BANANATEST]
END
```

The error is Syntax.

> Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 20 Database 'BANANATEST' does not
>   exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

While it is accurate, BANANATEST DB doesn't exist in the moment of query "compilation"... SQL Server doesn't realise that database **WILL** exist when it reaches this line.

**How can I make it work?** Either by ignoring syntax checks or whatever it make it work...

NOTE: The backup comes with a BANANATEST usr and I want to cover two scenarios:

1. LOGIN already exists in SQL Server
2. LOGIN does not exist

Comment: Use dynamic SQL so you don't get a compilation error when running this code.

Comment: Take this one step at a time.

Comment: Separate the `RESTORE` and `USE` into separate batches using a `GO`

Comment: I cannot use GO inside a BEGIN END :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around the go with #temp tables

```
CREATE table #temp12 (restore1  bit)
IF db_id('BANANATEST') is not null
 BEGIN   
  print 'DB BANANATEST already exists. NO ACTION TAKEN.'
 END
ELSE
 BEGIN
  print 'DB BANANATEST does NOT exist.'
  print 'Restoring a backup of BANANATEST'
  RESTORE DATABASE BANANATEST
   FROM DISK = 'BANANATEST.original.bak' ;
  INSERT INTO #temp12 VALUES ('1')
  print 'Creating User BANANATEST'
 END 
 GO
  USE master
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 from #TEMP12)
      BEGIN
      If Exists (select loginname from master.dbo.syslogins where name ='BANANATEST')
      Begin
       DROP LOGIN [BANANATEST]
      END
      CREATE LOGIN [BANANATEST] WITH PASSWORD=N'BANANATEST', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
      USE BANANATEST
      ALTER USER [BANANATEST] WITH LOGIN = [BANANATEST]
  END
DROP TABLE #temp12
```

Comment: It works ok. I edited your answer as there usually a #TEMP db in sql server already and restore is a reserverd word...